# Font size in message list for the Office 365 webmail

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

After my Company switched to Office 365 yesterday, I've found that the font for the list of messages for the new Office 365 webmail is too big.

As you can see from the image below, you can barely see 3-4 messages without the need to scroll.

Is there a way to make that font smaller? I've searched all the options without success.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In case others find this, I think I just found a solution (from [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/10/21/url-for-office-365-outlook-web-app-light/)) that lets you force the browser back to showing the Light version of OWA with 40-some messages listed at one line per, instead of the ridiculous modern tile version where you see 4.  Directly after the **/owa/** part of the URL you are using, paste in **?exsvurl=1&layout=light&wa=wsignin1.0**.  So if you are getting your webmail on office365, your URL will look like this:

```
 https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?exsvurl=1&layout=light&wa=wsignin1.0
```

Edit:  Testing it a bit, it seems like the only necessary part of that is **?layout=light** ... So try:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?layout=light
```

Answer (score -1):

These fonts are set in each application.  In Outlook, fonts for the lists are under Change View/Modify/Other Settings.

Comment: I don't seem to find the option you are talking about. Are you sure this is in the WEB application (not Outlook desktop)? Unfortunately, my webapp is in Italian...